How to center roman numeral page numbers using PHPWord
I'm attempting to generate lower case roman numeral page numbers that are centered in the footer of the page using PHPWord.  I've got the numbers showing up appropriately however, I can't figure out how I can tell PHPWord that the field should have an alignment of center.
 /**
 * Build the Abstract Page
 */
private function buildAbstractPage()
{

    $section = $this->phpWord->addSection(array('pageNumberingStart' => 2));

    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        $section->addText(
            '',
            null,
            array('alignment' => 'center', 'spacing' => 0)
        );
    }

    $section->addText(
        'Abstract',
        array('allCaps' => true),
        array('alignment' => 'center')
    );

    $section->addText(
        $this->submission->abstract,
    );

    // FIXME: Page numbers need to be centered
    $footer = $section->addFooter();
    $footer->addField('PAGE', array('format' => 'roman'));
    
}

